# Tornado WebSocket closes once a minute

Tags: websocket, tornado, google-closure

I'm using Closure client-side and Tornado server side. I create a socket:

```
this.socket =  goog.net.WebSocket(true)
```

and then open it:

```
this.socket.open(theSocketUrl)
```

Every works fine including messages being passed correctly. However, once per minute (once every 60 to 61 seconds), the socket closes and then reopens. There are no errors server-side and the Closure socket error event doesn't get called.

I've added logging to tornado and something seems to be calling on_connection_close() which then calls the socket's method on_close(). The close() method itself does not get called.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using nginx or some other reverse-proxy in front of your tornado server?  I've seen this happen when the proxy timeout elapses and then nginx closes the connection, causing the behavior you're seeing.

You can change the `proxy_send_timeout` and `proxy_read_timeout` in nginx to prevent this.  Just make sure that when you edit `proxy.conf`, you include it from your main `nginx.conf`.